# got into grub rescue after partition of c: drive in win 7

Tags: hp

I have windows 7 and ubuntu  installed on my hp pavilion. I partitioned the c: drive by shrink volume and created a simple volume in windows 7 . Then i shut down the laptop. After few minutes i started it and a black window appeared showing grub rescue>. What should i do to save both OS and all my data. Please help.

Comment: Go on a Ubuntu live system and attach to your question a screenshot of Gparted and the output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Answer (score 0):

modifying your partition size also caused your partition ID to change. This means grub doesn't know from which partition to boot. Let's say, your /boot directory is on your 2nd partition, aka sda2, then, if your system has traditional BIOS (not UEFI):
in the grub rescue do: `linux (hd0,2)/boot/linux-image-` and hit Tab for autocomlete (since I assume you don't know your kernel version) and enter, then `initrd (hd0,2)/boot/initr` and again hit Tab and enter. After that enter `boot`.

once booted, edit /etc/fstab as root and replace the old UUID with the correct UUID for each partition, which you get from the output of `blkid`. After that run `update-grub` as root.

Comment: Its not working. Actualy it is showing " error: no such partition grub rescue". What should i do ? What should i type ?

Comment: It is showing unknown commands whatever i type.

Comment: try other disk and partition numbers such as (hd0,3), (hd1,1), etc

Answer (score 0):

0h thank god ! The problem is solved by the following commands:-
grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos3)
error: bad filename
grub rescue>set boot=(hd0,msdos3)
grub rescue>set prefix=(hd0,msdos3)/boot/grub
grub rescue>insmod normal
 normal
[ hit enter after each command ].
Now after this i expanded c drive by deleting partition and now its working properly.